# Converter boxes, How to make it both output boxes work?

Tags: javascript, html, type-conversion, converters

I am doing a project of a converter. When I put a number in the number box, it shows up fine in the box2. But when I try to enter a number in box2, and it won't show the answer in box1. Can anyone help me? I don't know jquery and I am a starter of html and javascript. Hopefully, someone can help me. Thanks

```js
function NumberToSquare(num)
{ 
var sqrt; 
sqrt = Math.sqrt(num); 
return sqrt; 
} 

function SquareToNumber(sqrt)
{ 
var num; 
num = Math.pow(sqrt,2); 
return num; 
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Program Assignment 5</title>

<script type = text/javascript src = "calculate.js"> </script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
function ConvertToSqrt()
  //Assumes: Number contains a number
  //Results: displays the square root in box2
  {
    num = parseFloat(document.getElementById('box1').value);
    sqrt = NumberToSquare(num);
    box2.value=sqrt;
  }
  
  function ConvertToNum()
  //Assumes: Square contains a number of square root
  //Results: displays the number in box1
  {
    sqrt = parseFloat(document.getElementById('box2').value);
    num = SquareToNumber(sqrt);
    box1.value=num;
  }
</script>

</head>  

<body>
<div style="border: solid; width: 300px; background-color: #83CAFF">

<table>
<th></th> <th>Square Root Calculation</th>
<tr>
<th>Enter Number:</th><th><input type="number" id="box1" value=""></th>
<tr>
<th>SquareRoot:</th><th><input type="number" id="box2" value=""></th>
<tr>
<th></th><th><input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="ConvertToSqrt(); ConvertToNum();">
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: If box 1 is the input for box 2, then how can box 2 be the input for box 1 at the same time? You need a way to tell your code which one to use as the source. Maybe a `ToSqrt` button and a `ToSquared` button instead of just one button to try to do both.

Comment: So i should make another button? My teacher asks us to use the return value function, but I'm not quite sure what that is.

Comment: I've never heard of anything called the 'return value' function, but If I had to guess he/she means that you are to use a function that returns a value, which you already are.

Comment: So the only way that I can do is to make another button?

Comment: Another issue is that in ConvertToNum() and ConvertToSqrt(), you are using box1.value but you never defined box1.  Try using document.getElementById('box1').value

Comment: You know what they say about there being more than one way to skin a cat? I would add another button, but that isn't the only or necessarily the best way. It's just how I would do it.

Comment: Even after I fixed it, it still won't work. So there is no way to use one button to convert two values?

Comment: There are ways, it really depends on how complex you want to make it.  You can look at the most recently modified value, or when a value is changed by the user, the other field gets cleared.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps any, here's a quick sample.  It's not pretty but you can take what pieces you need and use it with your own.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script>
        function calc(which) {
            var newVal;
            if (which == "sqrt") {
                newVal = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num").value);
                newVal = Math.sqrt(newVal);
            }
            else if (which == "num") {
                newVal = parseFloat(document.getElementById("sqrt").value);
                newVal = Math.pow(newVal, 2);
            }

            document.getElementById(which).value = newVal;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width:400px;padding:25px;display:inline-block;line-height:150%;background-color:#83CAFF;font-weight:bold;border:solid 1px black;">
        <div style="width:200px;float:left;">
            <label>Number:</label>
            <br />
            <label>SquareRoot:</label>
        </div>
        <div style="width:200px;float:right;">
            <input type="number" id="num"/>
            <br />
            <input type="number" id="sqrt"/>
        </div>
        <button type="button" style="width:100%;" onclick="calc('sqrt');">Calc Sqrt</button>
        <button type="button" style="width:100%;" onclick="calc('num');">Calc Num</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks :) I will try that then.